# Discussion around bitwise operator statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am curious about a python statement:

```
csum = (N * (N + 1)) >> 1
```

where `N = 5` and `csum = 15`. I do not understand the operator `>>` and what's going on in this statement. What is the the under-the-hood thought behind this action? `csum` is supposed to be the cumulative sum of a vector 1:5.

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> `x >> y`
>   Returns `x` with the bits shifted to the right by `y` places. This
>   is the same as //'ing `x` by `2**y`.

In your statement python calculates the `(N * (N + 1))` part first then performs the `>>` operation between the result and the number 1:

```
In [4]: (N * (N + 1))
Out[4]: 30

In [5]: 30 >> 1
Out[5]: 15
```

Well, for a better demonstration you can simply convert your integers to binary using `bin()` function:

```
In [6]: bin(30)
Out[6]: '0b11110'
```

Now shift the bits to right by 1 and you'll get the following number:

```
01111
```

Now convert the result to integer using `int()` and 2 as the base:

```
In [11]: int('01111', 2)
Out[11]: 15
```

As another alternative way for calculating the right shift operation you can also use `operator.rshift()` function:

```
In [12]: from operator import rshift
In [13]: rshift(30, 1)
Out[13]: 15
```

Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

As mentioned in python wiki and @eryksun pointed out, you can also think of a right shift operation as dividing the 30 (left side number) by 2<sup>1 (right side number)</sup> which it would be easier to interpret when you convert your number to coefficients of 2 powers.

`bin(30)` is equal to `11110` which is:

1*2<sup>4</sup> + 1*2<sup>3</sup> + 1*2<sup>2</sup> + 1*2<sup>1</sup> + 0*2<sup>0</sup>

And by deviding with 2 you'll get:

1*2<sup>3</sup> + 1*2<sup>2</sup> + 1*2<sup>1</sup> + 1*2<sup>0</sup> + 0 = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15

Comment: It may be helpful to show the number written in base 2 as a sum of powers of two multiplied by {0, 1} coefficients, which you can generalize as `b0 * 2**0`, `b1 * 2**1`, etc. Then a right shift is basically subtracting 1 from the power of two for each coefficient, i.e. dividing the sum by 2.

Comment: @eryksun That's right. That's actually what the python wiki has mentioned. But I'll update the answer with your comment too ;).

Comment: A very detailed answer. Thank you very much for taking the time to enlighten me :-) I understand it now.

Comment: @Shejo284 Think noth'in of it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The operator `>>` is a shift right, in this case by 1.  It is roughly equivalent to integer divide by 2^N, so in this case divide by 2^1 (eg 2).  So:

```
csum = (N * (N + 1)) >> 1
```

where `N = 5`, is `5 * 6 / 2` which equals 15.

Which gives the cumulative sum for a one based incrementing vector such as `1:5`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Was a bit sloppy of me. Appreciate the answer. I understand :-)

Comment: It absolutely _is_ the cumulative sum. The sum is calculated as n(n+1)/2.

Comment: @JackAidley, thanks for the note, I missed the bit about it being a running vector.